# Four Square API: KeyError: 'venue'

Tags: python, api

I am unsure what i am doing wrong, I am trying extract foursquare Api data and have a list of restaurant by Borough,

```
'Neighborhood', 'ID', 'Name','ID','Rating','Tips'`
```

but i keep hitting `KeyError: 'venue'` . I am aware KeyError  is linked to  daily call quota set by Four Square. i also tried  checking key in dictionary , result is below. how do i retrieve the key?

```
    myDict = {'v': 'venue'}
```

print("Dictionary : ", myDict)

key = input("Please enter the Key you want to search for: ")

```
   # Check Whether the Given key exists in a Dictionary or Not
   if key in myDict.keys():
    print("\nKey Exists in this Dictionary")
   print("Key = ", key, " and Value = ", myDict[key])
   else:
    print("\nKey Does not Exists in this Dictionary") 

    OUTPUT
    Dictionary :  {'v': 'venue'}
   Please enter the Key you want to search for: v

 Key Exists in this Dictionary
   Key =  v  and Value =  venue
```

---

ORIGINAL ERROR

```
    def get_venue_details(venue_id):

CLIENT_ID = ' XXXX '# Foursquare ID, note there is a daily call quota limit 
CLIENT_SECRET =' XXXX' # Foursquare Secret, note there is a daily call quota it 
VERSION = '20180605' # Foursquare API version

#url to fetch data from foursquare api
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{}?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(
        venue_id,
        CLIENT_ID, 
        CLIENT_SECRET, 
        VERSION)

# get all the data
results = requests.get(url).json()
venue_data=results['response']['venue']
venue_details=[]
try:
    venue_id=venue_data['id']
    venue_name=venue_data['name']
    venue_likes=venue_data['likes']['count']
    venue_rating=venue_data['rating']
    venue_tips=venue_data['tips']['count']
    venue_details.append([venue_id,venue_name,venue_likes,venue_rating,venue_tips])
except KeyError:
    pass

column_names=['ID','Name','Likes','Rating','Tips']
df = pd.DataFrame(venue_details,columns=column_names)
return df

   for row in indian_rest_ny.values.tolist():
  Borough,Neighborhood,ID,Name=row
try:
    venue_details=get_venue_details(ID)
    print(venue_details)
    id,name,likes,rating,tips=venue_details.values.tolist()[0]
except IndexError:
    print('No data available for id=',ID)
    # we will assign 0 value for these resturants as they may have been 
    #recently opened or details does not exist in FourSquare Database
    id,name,likes,rating,tips=[0]*5
print('(',count,'/',len(indian_rest_ny),')','processed')
indian_rest_stats_ny = indian_rest_stats_ny.append({'Borough': Borough,
                                            'Neighborhood': Neighborhood, 
                                            'ID': id,
                                            'Name' : name,
                                            'Likes' : likes,
                                            'Rating' : rating,
                                            'Tips' : tips
                                           }, ignore_index=True)
```

### count+=1

```
      KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
      last)
   <ipython-input-16-10411ff430c3> in <module>
     8     Borough,Neighborhood,ID,Name=row
     9     try:
---> 10         venue_details=get_venue_details(ID)
     11         print(venue_details)
     12         id,name,likes,rating,tips=venue_details.values.tolist()[0]

   <ipython-input-4-8f4e1d8ebd9f> in get_venue_details(venue_id)
 14     # get all the data
 15     results = requests.get(url).json()
```

---> 16     venue_data=results['response']['venue']
     17     venue_details=[]
     18     try:

KeyError: 'venue'

---

> Copy from comments:

1. `requests.get(url).json()`
   resulted in `NameError: name 'url'` is not define.
2. derror occurred:

   ```
   venue_data=results['response']['venue']
   ```
3. please note this data is being extracted via Four Square API

   ```
   results = requests.get(url).json() 
   venue_data=results["response"]['groups'][0]['items'] 
   venue_details=[] 
   for row in venue_data: 
       try: 
           venue_id = row['venue']['id'] 
           venue_name=row['venue']['name'] 
           venue_category=row['venue']['categories'][0]['name'] 
           venue_details.append([venue_id,venue_name,venue_category]) 
       except KeyError: 
           pass column_names = ['ID','Name','Category'] 
           df = pd.DataFrame(venue_details,columns=column_names) 
           return df
   ```

Comment: Have you checked the `keys` of  `results['response']` to ensure that `['venue']` exists in the json?

Comment: how do i do that? if it  the code below, I was hit with NameError: name 'json_obj' is not defined                                                                                              
         def checkKey(json_obj, 'venue')

         if 'venue' in json_obj:
               print(json_obj['venue'])

Comment: `print(results)` or `print(results['response'])` or `print(results['response'].keys())`. In the case of the other error, you need to include the code that generated it in the question, but that says you never define `json_obj`. We can't help if you don;t show the code

Comment: i am sorry i am newbie to coding ang and slack. the full codes are found here: https://vanessamiranda.github.io/blog/data%20science/Battle_of_the_Locations/

Comment: There's no reason to apologize, everyone starts somewhere! Again, though, the key error indicates only that the key you're trying to use isn't present. Have you checked the output of your `requests.get(url).json()` to be sure that the key exists? If you think it's due to the lack of API response, then you also need to be checking the result of your `.get()` for a result or an error code. Unfortunately stack overflow isn't a code-writing service, and we also can't reproduce the error without your api access. The best bet is to go through line by line and determine where the error is occurring

Comment: Key Exists in this Dictionary. Key =  v  and Value =  venue/ please let me know how do i extract all the venue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error recently, and i found out I had used all my requests for the day on the Foursquare API.

You can get some more after registering a Credit Card on the site too.